# How can I obtain more Nintendo Switches?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Looking for a legitimate way to obtain more Nintendo Switches that's not tied to glitches or duping the item using the most recent way found.

I've made it a personal goal --  I want to spread the love of the Nintendo Switch to ALL of my island's residents. Unfortunately, it seems nigh impossible to achieve that goal, given that I only get a Nintendo Switch upon creating a new villager. The game only allows up to 4 local villagers, meaning even if I create 4 dummy villagers, the most I can achieve is 4 extra Nintendo Switches.

Is there a more reliable way to obtain extra Nintendo Switches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After opening Nook’s Cranny, I was able to order an additional Nintendo Switch from the Nook Stop. Check the catalog of furniture you’ve obtained - it should list the Nintendo Switch for 29,980 Bells.

I haven’t purchased it myself, so I can’t say for certain that you can buy multiples off of it. You can definitely buy an at least one additional, though, since I still have the first one in my house.

Comment: Is this the normal Nintendo Switch or the AC special edition posted by the others?

Comment: For me, it's the normal switch. Just to note: I have bought the regular, digital version of the game.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, it's possible to [order the ACNH Switch from Nook Shopping](https://youtu.be/SKKbCcDo550?t=7m20s).

Comment: Can you order the OG Switch, aka Red-Blue joycon Switch?

Comment: Yes, both the red/blue version and the ACNH version can show up in Nook Shopping

Answer (score 1):

I saw a post the other day showing Nook selling the Animal Crossing special edition Switch. I would expect that he can also sell the regular Switch.